# Command "node app.js" works but not for "npm run dev" when they basically run the same command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, package.json

**So I have an app.js like this:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

app.get("/accessToken", async (req, res) => {
    const clientId = "er234sfa";
    const clientSecret = "ce0f6dawdzca3222daa234cc43eaf5f42642";
    const url = "https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token";

    const base64 = btoa(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);
    let accessToken = "";
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": `Basic ${base64}`
        },
        data: {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            accessToken = response.data.access_token;
            console.log('access_token: ', accessToken);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error: ", error);
        })

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.json({
        access_token: accessToken
    });
});

app.listen(3100, () => {console.log(`Node JS is listening on port: 3100`)});
```

**My package.json looks like this:**

```
{
  "name": "backend-api-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Node JS API",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "api"
  ],
  "author": "Sen",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

But in terminal when I run command "node app.js", it will **work** when I call localhost:3100/accessToken and it will send me a response that gives an access token
**However** when I run command "npm run dev" in terminal, it will **not work** and show error like this:

```
error:  AxiosError: socket hang up
    at Function.AxiosError.from (C:\Github\SPECTA\backend-api-project\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:725:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (C:\Github\SPECTA\backend-api-project\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2467:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.<computed> (C:\Github\SPECTA\backend-api-project\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:466:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: null },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization: 'Basic MgeODg2YWszYjAaWdjI0NadOWNjNDNwdaY1ZjhmMmU2NDI=',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.1.3',
      'Content-Length': '29',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      [Symbol(defaults)]: [Object]
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: 'https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: [Object: null prototype],
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: [Object],
      hostname: 'proxy.intra.bca.co.id',
      port: '8080',
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: 'https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 29,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'POST https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic MgeODg2YWszYjAaWdjI0NadOWNjNDNwdaY1ZjhmMmU2NDI=\r\n' +
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.1.3\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 29\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'host: sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: 'https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'proxy.intra.bca.co.id',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id/auth/realms/3scale-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:466:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea to solve it and why? Since command "npm run dev" and "node app.js" both of them run "node app.js", why would "npm run dev" doesn't work? Any solution?

Comment: Why do you need to set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED?

Comment: I'm getting "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sso-apigw-int.dti.co.id" in both cases